# Parsing huge XML file for getting information from huge CSV file

Tags: php, xml, csv

I have huge problem.

I have a task to put in database information about products. All information's except price are in **XML file that is big 100mb**.

In another file there are information's about price of that product. That is **CSV file with size about 200mb**

In simple logic

1. Parse XML into array
2. Search price by unique ID of product in another file
3. Add found price to element of array where is that product
4. Put information's in database

But i Cannot do that. Problem is in **SIZE**.

I manage to parse XML and put it in array, but I cannot handle CSV file. If there is 1000 products, for each product he need to parse CSV file (that CSV file have more than 30.000.000 lines). I cannot parse that CSV one, much less 1000.

**I need suggestion how to solve this problem**

Comment: What happens when you try? Show your code and any error messages. Maybe you need to raise your memory limit?

Comment: `Problem is in SIZE.` use XMLReader and parse it NOT into an array and use fopen,fread,fclose for the csv (also not parse it fully into memory). That is a good way start.

Comment: You can also parse the CSV first fully into a temporary database (csv-header as table-fields) before you parse the XML. Then use the DB-CSV Data (lookup in the tabel instaed of the csv-file).

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I am parsing in with XMLReader and not doing whole file at once, thats ok. I have problem to read line line by line CSV, cause there are more than 30 millions of lines, so PHP cant do enough "fgetcsv" in  ten minutes, and i need faster way (if there is).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a job for a database to me. Load both files into a database and then do a simple join.

Comment: you think that putting 200mb file in database and searching is not to big problem ? And what is the best way to import that kind of file in database. What kind of queries ?

Comment: I'm afraid we're now talking about system design and architecture, technology selection, and a whole host of things that are outside the scope of StackOverflow. I do appreciate that my one-line answer was something you wouldn't be able to implement in 5 minutes, and indeed that there might well be project constraints I don't know about that make the whole approach infeasible.

Answer (score 1):

Use [XMLReader for the XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112985/how-do-i-get-a-50mb-zip-file-with-a-600mb-xml-file-into-a-mysql-datatable/32117345#32117345), [SplFileObject for the CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19825065/2265374).

Do not keep the information in memory. Write it directly into a database like MySQL or SQlite. After all the data is imported you can use SQL to aggregate it.